# Pandas' to_datetime function doesn't change dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have been recently working with python and I have found an issue I can't seem to solve. I am using a pandas dataset and when I want to change the dtype of a variable from 'object' to 'datetime64' using the to_datetime function, it does not changes it to the desired 'datetime64' dtype.

So far I only tried the to_datetime function, but that can't seem to solve the problem. I am looking for a solution to make to_datetime work or any other code that could change my variable's dtype from 'object' to 'datetime64'

Here you can find info about the dataset:

```py
df.head()
Formatted Date                      Summary  Precip Type Temperature (C)   Apparent Temperature (C)   Humidity   Wind Speed (km/h)   Wind Bearing (degrees)  Visibility (km)  Loud Cover Pressure (millibars)   Daily Summary
0   2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200   Partly Cloudy   rain    9.472222    7.388889    0.89    14.1197     251.0   15.8263     0.0     1015.13     Partly cloudy throughout the day.
1   2006-04-01 01:00:00.000 +0200   Partly Cloudy   rain    9.355556    7.227778    0.86    14.2646     259.0   15.8263     0.0     1015.63     Partly cloudy throughout the day.
2   2006-04-01 02:00:00.000 +0200   Mostly Cloudy   rain    9.377778    9.377778    0.89    3.9284  204.0   14.9569     0.0     1015.94     Partly cloudy throughout the day.
3   2006-04-01 03:00:00.000 +0200   Partly Cloudy   rain    8.288889    5.944444    0.83    14.1036     269.0   15.8263     0.0     1016.41     Partly cloudy throughout the day.
4   2006-04-01 04:00:00.000 +0200   Mostly Cloudy   rain    8.755556    6.977778    0.83    11.0446     259.0   15.8263     0.0     1016.51     Partly cloudy throughout the day.
```

And here you can see the dtypes before using the to_datetime function:

```py
df.dtypes
Formatted Date               object
Summary                      object
Precip Type                  object
Temperature (C)             float64
Apparent Temperature (C)    float64
Humidity                    float64
Wind Speed (km/h)           float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)      float64
Visibility (km)             float64
Loud Cover                  float64
Pressure (millibars)        float64
Daily Summary                object
dtype: object
```

Here after using the to_datetime function:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Formatted Date'])
df.dtypes

Formatted Date               object
Summary                      object
Precip Type                  object
Temperature (C)             float64
Apparent Temperature (C)    float64
Humidity                    float64
Wind Speed (km/h)           float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)      float64
Visibility (km)             float64
Loud Cover                  float64
Pressure (millibars)        float64
Daily Summary                object
Date                         object
dtype: object
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there maybe `NaN`s in the `Formatted Date` column? Does the problem reproduce on a small dataframe (i.e. taking only the head as a dataframe)?

Comment: Using only the top 5 rows, the problem does not reproduce on my end. So... I'm guessing there are rows that can't pass through `to_datetime`

Comment: Look at `df['Formatted Date'].describe()` to see if there are NaN/NaT rows. Then you might want to impute the NaN/NaT values with some sentinel so the column can convert

Comment: count                             96453
unique                            96429
top       2010-08-02 15:00:00.000 +0200
freq                                  2
Name: Formatted Date, dtype: object
It looks like there's no NaN/NaT rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `pandas>=0.24` you need to add the parameter `utc=True`.

```
import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('weatherHistory.csv')

df['Date'] = df['Formatted Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime, utc=True)
```

```
df.dtypes
Formatted Date                           object
Summary                                  object
Precip Type                              object
Temperature (C)                         float64
Apparent Temperature (C)                float64
Humidity                                float64
Wind Speed (km/h)                       float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)                  float64
Visibility (km)                         float64
Loud Cover                              float64
Pressure (millibars)                    float64
Daily Summary                            object
Date                        datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

You want to change the `dtype` value from `object` to `datetime64`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col':["2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200"]})
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
col    object
dtype: object
```

## Solution

To change the type, you need to apply `pd.to_datetime`.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
col    datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]
dtype: object
```

If this does not work, then your column `Formatted Date` might contain inconsistent date formats or `NaN` values.

## Real data

Using your dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/budincsevity/szeged-weather/):

```
import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv('weatherHistory.csv')
```

```
df.dtypes
Formatted Date               object
Summary                      object
Precip Type                  object
Temperature (C)             float64
Apparent Temperature (C)    float64
Humidity                    float64
Wind Speed (km/h)           float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)      float64
Visibility (km)             float64
Loud Cover                  float64
Pressure (millibars)        float64
Daily Summary                object
dtype: object
```

```
df['Date'] = df['Formatted Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

```
df.dtypes
Formatted Date                      object
Summary                             object
Precip Type                         object
Temperature (C)                    float64
Apparent Temperature (C)           float64
Humidity                           float64
Wind Speed (km/h)                  float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)             float64
Visibility (km)                    float64
Loud Cover                         float64
Pressure (millibars)               float64
Daily Summary                       object
Date                        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the comment. Sadly, this did not solve the issue.
I am using a public dataset from keagle.
https://www.kaggle.com/budincsevity/szeged-weather
Maybe testing the real dataframe is of more use to check the error

Comment: I tried your dataset, it works with the code above. Which python version and pandas version do you use? Tested with `Python 3.6.4` and `Pandas 0.22.0`.

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.3 and Pandas 0.24.2 and with these versions this solution does not workj

Answer (score 2):

I've been in trouble with pandas and acessing elements by column labels.
I made a reduced version of your dataframe and could change the column dataype using the location of the column by index.

Try to change your:

```
 pd.to_datetime(df['Formatted Date'])
```

to:

```
  pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0])
```

It worked for me:

```
  data=['2006-04-01 00:00:00.000 +0200']

  df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  df2 = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0])

  print(df2.dtypes)
```

The output was:

```
  datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]
```

I downloaded the same data you are using and I think it may be a possible solution for your dataset, just extending your original code to deal with date format:

```
  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Formatted Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %p', errors= 'coerce')
```

As you can see the column "Date" has the correct datatype now:

```
Formatted Date                      object
Summary                             object
Precip Type                         object
Temperature (C)                    float64
Apparent Temperature (C)           float64
Humidity                           float64
Wind Speed (km/h)                  float64
Wind Bearing (degrees)             float64
Visibility (km)                    float64
Loud Cover                         float64
Pressure (millibars)               float64
Daily Summary                       object
Date                        datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I have tried this to change the whole column into a datetime:
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0])

But it didn't do the trick :/

Comment: I've just added another solution. It was tested with the kaggle dataset and worked.

Comment: This now does create the 'Date' column, however it doesn't populate it with data from the 'Formatted Date' column